# Entity Framework 4.0 Insert/Update

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I was hoping there is a way to use the same code to both insert and update.

For example, I insert a new client like the below using the entity framework.

```
using (var context = new GenWebEntities())
{
  clientObj = new Client();

  var client = new Client
  {
    FirstName = "John",
    LastName = "Smith"
  };
  clientObj = client;

  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And If I could use the same code to update the client as well, I would not have to write double the code.

```
using (var context = new GenWebEntities())
{
  clientObj = context.Clients.Single(c => c.ClientId == 31);

  var client = new Client
  {
    FirstName = "Johnathan", // Updated First Name
    LastName = "Rock" // Updated Last name
  };
  clientObj = client;

  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If there is one way to code for both the insert and update, I would love to know how as this method above just inserts a new record.

** UPDATE **
The problem I run into with this solution is I have a one to many relationship.

Example:

I have another table ClientPayment that is one to many.  So when I need to update the ClientPayment how do I reference this table for the update?

For the insert I would normaly do:

```
client.ClientPayments.Add(new ClientPayment { Type = "Credit Card", CardNumber = "4111-1111-1111-1111")
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think your existing code is doing what you think it's doing.  If you want to add a new object to the context, use `context.Add(newClient)`. If you grab an object out of the DB with the `context.Clients` IQueryable, you don't need to create a new object. You can just change the properties of `clientObj` and call `SaveChanges`.

So, the only difference between an "insert" (saving a new object) and an update (saving a changed object) is that you have to do `context.Clients.Add` before the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```
private void SaveAndUpdate(int? ClientId)
{
    using (var context = new GenWebEntities())
    {
        Client client;
        if(ClientId.HasValue)
            client=context.Clients.Single(c => c.ClientId == ClientId.Value);
        else
            client = new Client();

        client.FirstName = "Johnathan";
        client.LastName = "Rock";

        if(!ClientId.HasValue)
            context.Clients.Add(client)

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I run into with this solution is I have a one to many relationship. 

Example:

I have another table ClientPayment that is one to many.  So when I need to update the ClientPayment how do I reference this table for the update?

For the insert I would normaly do:

    client.ClientPayments.Add(new ClientPayment { Type = "Credit Card", CardNumber = "4111-1111-1111-1111")

I updated my question, so that this is more readable.

Comment: Is this only added when you are creating a new. Or should this be updated as well?

Comment: When I create a new client I need to add a a payment method.  But also I need to be able to update the payment as well.